# Rails route constraint for number (month). Leading zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, constraints

I'm not very good at writing regular expressions for *Rails routes*.

I want to have numbers from 1 to 12 valid (since it is, basically, number of month), however, I would also like to have numbers from **01** to **09** valid as well, so that leading zero for a single number was valid.

Could someone help me with this one ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) a good place to start.

You're looking for something like this:

```
^0?[1-9]|1[0-2]$
```

The `^` and `$` match the beginning and end so you don't match nonsense like `a09b`. The `|` is like an OR statement and has lowest precedence, so to the left of it, `0?[1-9]` says any *one* of the characters `1-9` preceded by an *optional* `0`, and to the right of it, `1[12]` says any *one* of the characters `12` preceded by a *required* 1.

Comment: You are missing the 0 for 10.  Should be `1[012]$`

Comment: but 1-9 with any number of leading zeros is still valid so check that too. for 1 to 9 "^0*[1-9]$". checkout www.rubular.com

Comment: @Dmitri, the regex in this answer is incorrect (see the comments above) so make sure you include the extra zero and the * after the first zero like surase.prasad and I mentioned.

Comment: @link664 - You're right. It's 3:00am here; my brain's still waking up, sorry. Editing.

Comment: @surase.prasad - Not sure I agree, but that's up to the OP. I imagined something like a MM/DD/YYYY format where he _wouldn't_ want a 3-digit month.

Comment: Upvote for a more details answer now that the edit has been made :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex: `/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$/`